# access file non exclusively with stream VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, upload, ftp, file-access

i am using [OpenDotNetFTPlib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dotnetftplib/files/) to upload a file to multiple FTP's at the same time. To do so i declared multiple instances of the ftp client. Its working and its processing everything as expected, except for one thing: The problem i am facing is that the Library is taking exclusive access to the file. So if i am uploading to the first FTP the second instance of the client doesnt get access to the file because its beeing read by the other process.

Could somebody please tell me how to access the file i a non exclusive way?

Comment: Why don't you download the source code from SourceForge and look inside to find out?

Comment: because my knowledge is way to low... (and i mean WAY to low..)

Comment: From their source code: they open the file to read it this was `using (FileStream fs = File.Open( Path.Combine( localDirectory, localFilename ), FileMode.Open ))` (DotNetFtpLib.cs, line 171). Which means it opens the file without sharing. So either change the source code and recompile, or find another library.

Comment: done and works thanks! please post it as answer so i can accept!